# Python Pandas .loc need count of column; null for one column and value in another column

Tags: sql, pandas, numpy, pandas-loc

I am trying to create a pandas .loc statement that would get the count of rows in one column where the value is not null and where the value of a different column is 1.

(I could do this same query in SQL in seconds, but I'm new to using pandas.)
One column is BAD. The other column is DELINQ. The correlation in SQL would be

```
select count(DELINQ) from DATA where BAD = 1 and DELINQ is not null;
```

In the following code, I have the counts of the column DELINQ, where BAD = 1, but I don't know how to add the second criteria where DELINQ is not null.
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("hmeq_reduced.csv")
print('BAD: ',data.loc[data.BAD == 1,"DELINQ"].count())
print('Not Bad: ',data.loc[data.BAD == 0,"DELINQ"].count())
```

The results are:

```
BAD:  22
Not Bad:  5
```

Here is the sample data set...hmeq_reduced:

```
BAD DELINQ
1   0
1   2
1   0
1   
0   0
1   0
1   2
1   0
1   2
1   0
1   
1   1
1   0
0   0
1   1
1   1
1   6
1   
1   0
0   0
1   1
1   0
1   0
1   2
1   0
1   0
0   0
1   0
1   2
0   0
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Actually, this seems to be working. Not sure what I was thinking before. Probably just too tired.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
len(df[(df.BAD == 1) & (df.DELINQ != "")])
```

**For example - here is the full code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'BAD': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                    'DELINQ': [0.0, 2.0, 0.0,"", 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0,"", 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 6.0,"", 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0]})

print(len(df[(df.BAD == 1) & (df.DELINQ != "")]))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
22
```

### Note:

If the blanks are stored as `np.nan`, then you could use

```
len(df[(df.BAD == 1) & (df.DELINQ.notnull())])
```